# Выводится только одна строчка из базы данных sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, discord

Мне нужно чтобы мне выводило все строки из базы данных, но выводит лишь одну строчку:

[image: Вот что мне выводит.]

А мне нужно чтобы выводило полностью всё (пример.):

[image: А вот как должно выводить.]

Мой код:

```
@bot.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, data FROM logs ORDER BY data")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        embed=disnake.Embed(
            title="Logi",
            color=0x36393f
        )
        embed.add_field(name="Info", value=row[0], inline="true")
        embed.add_field(name="Data", value=row[1], inline="true")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно вынести создание объекта Embed из блока цикла. Могу более подробно помочь в работе с базой или discord.py, свяжись со мной в discord Хомяк#8241.

```py
@bot.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    cursor.execute("SELECT name, data FROM logs ORDER BY data")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    embed=disnake.Embed(
            title="Logi",
            color=0x36393f
        )
    for row in rows:
        embed.add_field(name="Info", value=row[0], inline="true")
        embed.add_field(name="Data", value=row[1], inline="true")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```